# Regex to match digits only if not followed or proceeded by letters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match digits but not when they are within words (in JavaScript).

The following should match:

```
1
1,2
1.5-4 (matches 1.5 & 4 separately)
(1+3) (matches 1 & 3 separately)
=1;
```

The following should NOT match:

```
FF3D
3deg
```

I thought I could solve with with a negative lookahead, like so: `(?![A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+[\.|\,]?[0-9]?)` but it does not work.

How can I best solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [`(?<!\w)\d(?!\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ez0RSh/1)

Comment: See [`\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/fRM2Ng/2). Your question is not quite clear though: why do you use a `,` in your regex? To support comma as a decimal separator?

Comment: Yes, as separators, added the example above.

Comment: So, did my solution work? Shall I post for you to accept? Or do you also plan to match `.455` and `,445` like numbers?

Comment: FF3D isn't a word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2021 update:**

Since lookbehind support has grown considerably, it makes sense to use a lookbehind based solution:

```js
/(?<![a-z])\d*[.,]?\d+(?![a-z])/gi         # ASCII only
/(?<!\p{L})\p{N}*[.,]?\p{N}+(?!\p{L})/giu  # Unicode-aware
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P1lcZg/1). Please track the [lookbehind and Unicode property class support here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/).

*Details*

- `(?<![a-z])` - no ASCII letter (or any Unicode letter if `\p{L}` is used) allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d*[.,]?\d+`
- `(?![a-z])` - no ASCII letter (or any Unicode letter if `\p{L}` is used) allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

**Original answer**

In order to match any standalone integer or float numbers with dot or comma as decimal separator you need

```
/(?:\b\d+[,.]|\B[.,])?\d+\b/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sxk52T/1). The point here is that you cannot use a word boundary `\b` before a `.` since it will invalidate all matches like `.55` (only `55` will be matched).

**Details**:

- `(?:\b\d+[,.]|\B[.,])?` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\b\d+[,.]` - a word boundary (there must be a non-word char before or start of string), then 1+ digits, and then a `.` or `,`
  - `|` - or
  - `\B[.,]` - a position other than word boundary (only a non-word char or start of string) and then a `.` or `,`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

```js
const regex = /(?:\b\d+[,.]|\B[.,])?\d+\b/g;
const str = `.455 and ,445 44,5345 435.54 4444
1
1,2
1.5-4
(1+3)
=1;

FF3D
3deg`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

If you need to also add support for the exponent use:

```
/(?:\b\d+[,.]|\B[.,])?\d+(?:e[-+]?\d+)?\b/ig
```

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to match digits but not when they are within words.

You can use look arounds in your regex:

```
\b\d*[,.]?\d+\b
```

- `\b` is for word boundary

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ez0RSh/4)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am trying to achieve this in JavaScript. According to http://www.regexr.com/ `lookbehind` are not supported in JS. :( Is there another solution? If nothing else is working, maybe by specifying all allowd characters before and after?

Comment: ok Javascript wasn't mentioned earlier. I have updated my answer based on your latest edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var pattern= /([\d.]+)/;
```

https://regex101.com/r/q1qDHV/1